# Add JIRA Quick Search to Chrome Omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, jira, opensearch

I would like to search JIRA's "Quick Search" from Chrome's Omnibox.  This is not the same as this Chrome Omnibox search string:

```
https://myserver/jira/browse/%s
```

That string will only open perfectly (not partially) matched JIRA IDs.  A Quick Search will automatically open the issue that uniquely matches the search criteria--even if the search criteria is a partial match.  For example, consider a system where there is only one JIRA issue that contains -77, and that JIRA issue is CLS-77.  Using Quick Search (at the upper-right corner of the JIRA site) to search for "77" will open issue CLS-77 automatically.  Performing the same search through Chrome Omnibox custom search string I listed earlier will not launch CLS-77 when searching for 77.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In newer versions of JIRA (I'm using 6.2.7), the URL to use is https://jira.example.com/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=%s (replace jira.example.com with your host name).

**Update:** In JIRA 6.4.4, this URL works: https://jira.example.com/issues/?jql=%s

Comment: The updated string doesn't work quite as before: now, you have to put in a valid query. To get the closer to the old behaviour, a better string is ...//jira.example.com/issues/?jql=text~"%s"%20or%20id="%s". It isn't quite the same since it leaves you on the search page even if an exact id is entered. It is good enough for my needs though.

Answer (score 67):

In searching for the same answer, I discovered a partial solution.  This solution requires that you use the keyword searching feature of the omnibox, so searching for "ISSUE-123" will not work but "jira ISSUE-123" will.  It also supports quick-search text searching for example "jira some search string."

In chrome, follow these steps to configure:

1. Open chrome's settings and click **Manage Search Engines** in the
   search section.
2. Scroll to the bottom and enter the following information:

   - Search engine name: **JIRA** (or some description about which instance of jira like "Apache JIRA")
   - Keyword: **jira** (or something simple to remember on the omnibox, could be the base URL of your jira instance)
   - URL: **https://jira.example.com/jira/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=%s** (obviously, replace the jira.example.com with the host name of your jira instance)
3. Click done

To use:

1. In the omnibox type **jira** (or your keyword you configured above) followed by a tab or space
2. Enter your quick-search term which could be an issue key, free-form text or project text

Examples of what to type in the OmniBox:

- An issue key: **jira WEB-123**
- Free-form text: **jira Logo change**
- Project-specific search: **jira WEB logo**

Comment: Would it be possible to add a keyboard shortcut. For example the default for google search is CTRL-K.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use Setting>Search Engine>Manage Search Engines and add your URL https://yourjirasite/secure/QuickSearch.jspa?searchString=%s  and set your 'keyword' to something quick, like 'jira' or 'j'.

Then from the chrome omnibox you can type "j MyProject-1234" and find your Jira right away. or  "j FooBar" to find all the FooBar related Issues.

Comment: You solution appears to be a rehash of the accepted solution provided 3.5 years ago and the more detailed rewording of that same solution provided almost 3 years ago.